# Number of "double" surjections from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $\{1,2,\ldots, m\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I know about number of surjective functions from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to  $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$. I was wondering is there some way to find number of functions $f$ from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to  $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ such that  $\forall y \in \{1,2,\ldots,m\}\;\exists x,z \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}, x\neq z$ such that $f(x)=y$ and $f(z)=y$.
I was trying to use inclusion exclusion formula but it seems that there are many cases.
Is there some "trick" to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Write $[n] = \{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$. A surjection $f : [n] \to [m]$ amounts to a (labeled) partition of $[n]$ into $m$ non-empty subsets, namely the fibers of $f$; these are counted by the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $\left\{ n \atop m \right\} m!$. You are asking for a (labeled) partition of $[n]$ into $m$ subsets of size at least $2$. These are counted by a variant of the Stirling numbers of the second kind, which can be described using a two-variable generating function

$$\exp \left( \sum_{k \ge 2} z \frac{t^k}{k!} \right) = \exp \left( z \left( e^t - t - 1 \right) \right) = \sum_{n, m \ge 0} f_{n, m} z^m \frac{t^n}{n!}.$$

Here $f_{n, m}$ counts unlabeled partitions and to get labeled ones we multiply by $m!$ as before. There are several things you can do from here, for example you can write down an expression for $f_{n, m}$ in terms of the Stirling numbers by factoring out the $\exp(-zt)$, which corresponds to some inclusion-exclusion argument. You can also expand out $\exp(z(e^t - t - 1))$ to get a formula somewhat similar to one of the formulas for the Stirling numbers but more complicated. It depends on what you want to do.